# How can i change the color when my app is very small in zoom?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

When i minimize my app, appear white space, i want to change that color, i dont like white, i want black

there are in the bottom a blank space

The blank space section it does not belong to my body or header or my footer, my question is, how can i change the color?

this worked, but just in navigator like this

just i wrote background-color so:

```
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: black;
}
```

**this is my code App.js in vuejs3 (does not worked btw)**

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="app">
    <LayoutDefault >
      <router-view class="content" />
    </LayoutDefault>
  </div>
</template>

...

<style scoped>
  .content {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 700px;
     background-color: black !important;
  }
  body {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    min-height: 100vh !important;
     background-color: black !important;
}
 .app {
    background-color: black !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is no option to track zoom changes in css. You can workaround the problem by setting

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: it does not worked

Comment: Can you give a source code so that I first try it myself first?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to give this background to body's itself. I think it will be enough. But if you will show your code, you will get better answers.

Comment: to which body? i can not to catch the blank section